# How to calculate the average score in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, taxonomy, average

Perhaps someone can assist me with the following how to get the average score in this taxonomy list.

I have a SharePoint list as follows:

```
Taxonomy Name     Score     Average Score

Taxonomy1           4             3.67
Taxonomy1           4             3.67
Taxonomy1           3             3.67
Taxonomy2           9              5
Taxonomy2           1              5
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify view, group by "Taxonomy Name", in Total section, set "Average" for score:

[image]

Then the list looks like the following:

[image]